# NEO4J MATCH query returns incorrect output

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a simple query to search for a relationship based on a property uuid:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->() where r.uuid = '**ab7544ce-9d85-4033-867a-b9d80c6c7b07**' return r

[{'r': (1917411)-[:Gets_Over_By {finish_date: '2020-04-02', percent_alloc: 1.0, start_date: '2020-03-16', uuid: '**e6d16fef-b2c8-482c-ad4c-9e13306545de**'}]->(1917385)}]
```

However, only sometimes (once in about 200 times) when I run this query, I get the incorrect output when I search through my **Python** program where I use **py2neo.Graph** package. However, if I query through the neo4j browser on windows, it returns the correct relationship.

I use the `graph.run(cypher_query)` method to execute the cypher queries.
I use neo4j-community-3.4.11.

I have no idea what could be wrong so any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you properly trapping errors and clearing buffers?    Is it possible that an error occurred and these are the results from a previous query.

Comment: That is a possibility, but what I dont understand is why the neo4j browser gives me the correct output?

Comment: My reasoning is simple (I have so little information to go on), but basically from experience I can say that any API being called programmatically (high call count) is guaranteed to eventually encounter an error condition of some kind (e.g. a network blip). However, 1. manual queries in the browser would rarely if ever encounter a rare blip, 2. I'm confident queries in the browser will either show an error or the correct result (but never silently ignore an error then show the previous result still stored in the variable)